# aurelia.js - custom binding engine?

Tags: knockout.js, aurelia, clusterize

found next phrase:

> The system is pluggable and will let developers teach it new ways of observing properties so you can easily plug in custom model/view-model libraries such as Knockout, Breeze, Backbone, etc. which may have their own mechanism for storing properties and raising change events.

but not found examples - how it can be used (just because can't imagine how to "bind" some data to template in terms of aurelia, that not attached to document yet... and update this data later)

P.S. I need to write custom element using **clusterize.js** for **aurelia.js** and have no luck at this moment.

Comment: I've removed my answer, because unfortunatle the repository for aurelia-knockout was deleted yesterday, december 18th 2015. You can still see it in google's cache. Perhaps you can contact the author https://github.com/jdanyow and ask him about it. As you can see, he has many resources devoted to Aurelia.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to write a custom-element using a library called `SomeLibrary`:

```
import {inject, DOM} from 'aurelia-framework';
import SomeLibrary from './someLibrary';

@inject(DOM.Element)
export class MyElement {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    //this method will be called by convetions
    bind() {
       //Do your magic here, using SomeLibrary and this.element
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

There is no need to import `DOM.Element` anymore. A simple `inject(Element)` without any import statement should be enough.

Comment: The main question in this case: How to "bind" some data to template, that not attached to document yet... and update this data later?

Comment: if the data is not attached to the document, how would you bind this to the element? Perhaps you have to hit the database or another source, bindable properties might be a solution as well. Provide more information about your problem, show what you have done so far. Then, I'll be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by Crisim II Numeroano for saying that now there is another available github project: [aurelia-knockout](https://github.com/code-chris/aurelia-knockout). (A previous one in  https://github.com/jdanyow was deleted on dec 18th 2015).

The documentation that shows how to use `ko` with `Aurelia`: [Aurelia's Adaptive Binding](http://blog.aurelia.io/2015/04/03/aurelia-adaptive-binding/) includes information on how to implement custom bindings for Aurelia. Perhaps you can get some inspiration from the Breeze plugin in this page to implement a new one for ko. Or contact the author of the deleted plugin.

Comment: I've written the author of that plugin. I hope I'll get an asnwer from him, so that I can add extra info to this answer.

Comment: if anyone is interested in this, you can use [aurelia-knockout](https://github.com/code-chris/aurelia-knockout)